# Take parent directory path from a filesystem path in bash

Tags: bash

I need help in bash script:

Let's say I have a `bash.sh` file such as:

```
cat 
$1Viral_sequences_loci/Fasta_viral_loci_seq_* > $1Viral_sequences_loci/All_fasta_viral_loci.fna
```

and I run bash `bash.sh /path1/path2/path3/`

so I would replace `$1` by `/path1/path2/path3/`:

```
cat 
/path1/path2/path3/Viral_sequences_loci/Fasta_viral_loci_seq_* > /path1/path2/path3/Viral_sequences_loci/All_fasta_viral_loci.fna
```

but what if I want to reduce only from one order in the path for instance:

```
cat 
/path1/path2/path3/Viral_sequences_loci/Fasta_viral_loci_seq_* > /path1/path2/Viral_sequences_loci/All_fasta_viral_loci.fna
```

where the second `$1` is not `/path1/path2/path3/` but `/path1/path2/`

Comment: If the second is completely different from the first, use two parameters instead of one. This is also the most flexible solution. If you always can derive the second from the first like in your example, use the approach suggested by Michal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"${1%/*/}/"` removes the shortest possible suffix pattern matched by bash's `*` including the trailing `/` following the previous `/`, and then re-adds the `/`. With `shopt -s extglob`, `?(/)` could be used for that trailing `/` to make it optional.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Comment: @NathanOliver yea i know but wanted to answer fast and then edit

Comment: Please don't try to be the fastest gun in the west.  All you do is hurt the quality of the site while your answer is in a less than ideal state.

Comment: @chippycentra yeah i pasted the wrong thing. fixed.

Comment: @chippycentra yay, i got points — thanks for bothering to click accept